# Ansible multiple vars/value

Tags: ansible, bind9

I need to role which adds records to my zones (bind9)

In hostvars I created vars like as below:

```
zones:
    zone.name1:
      - [ type: A, name: mike, ip: 192.168.1.10 ]
      - [ type: A, name: bob, ip: 192.168.1.11 ]

    zone.name2:
      - [ type: A, name: alice, ip: 192.168.1.12 ]
      - [ type: A, name: joanne, ip: 192.168.1.13 ]
```

In role/tasks/main.yaml

```
- lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/bind/zones/{{ item }}.zone"
    line: '@   IN   "{{ item.value.type }}"   "{{ item.value.name }}" "{{ item.value.i }}"'
  with_items: "{{ zones | dict2items }}"
```

How to get a result which adds a new record to the zone file?

Comment: What is it currently doing, what do you wish it was doing, and what error is your current attempt producing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of things wrong here.

1. You are using `list` notation for `dict` (`[ type: A, name: mike, ip: 192.168.1.10 ]` should be `{ type: A, name: mike, ip: 192.168.1.10 }`)
2. Your data structure requires two loops which you cannot do directly in the playbook.
3. You probably also want to have the freedom to remove records when they are not needed which doesn't work just like that when using `lineinfile`.

The following solution fixes all the above problems:

```
# main.yaml

---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    zones:
      zone.name1:
        - { type: A, name: mike, ip: 192.168.1.10 }
        # Remove this record
        - { type: A, name: bob,  ip: 192.168.1.11, state: absent }
      zone.name2:
        - { type: A, name: alice,  ip: 192.168.1.12 }
        - { type: A, name: joanne, ip: 192.168.1.13 }
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: lines.yaml
      loop: "{{ zones | dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: records
```

Another task file which we loop through:

```
# lines.yaml

---

- lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/{{ records.key }}.zone
    line: >-
      @   IN   "{{ item.type }}"   "{{ item.name }}" "{{ item.ip }}"
    regexp: >-
      ^@\s+IN\s+"{{ item.type }}"\s+"{{ item.name }}"\s+"{{ item.ip }}"$
    state: >-
      {{ 'present' if 'state' not in item or item.state == 'present' else 'absent' }}
  loop: "{{ records.value }}"
```

Execute it with this command:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, --diff main.yaml
```